# fs.readFileSync says 'no such file or directory' although require() returns the file correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to read a JSON file dynamically. This is why `require()` won't cut it. It doesn't simply update the file until NodeJS server restarts. This is why I have to use `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync`.

When I use, `const data = require("../data.json");` it just reads it properly. No issues at all, but like I said, it doesn't update dynamically.

When I use `const data = () => fs.readFileSync("../data.json", { encoding: "utf8" });` it simply returns `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../data.json'`

I also tried `fs.readFile`. Doesn't work.

Most weirdly, when I try to read another json file with `fs.readFileSync`, I'm seeing values that I changed days ago. It reads an old version. I don't understand. That old version doesn't exist anymore. I manually checked.

I tried `npm install`, `npm cache clean --force`. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Use an absolute path so you're sure it's not an issue with CWD.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably looking for `require.resolve` if you're working with CommonJS modules in Node. This will use the internals of `require` to provide the absolute path string to the file you want to read in.

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireresolverequest-options

Comment: `const data = () => fs.readFileSync(require.resolve("../data.json"), { encoding: "utf8" });` This solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for help, this solved my issue as well

Answer (score 8):

`require` takes a path relative to the directory the module file is in.

`readFileSync` takes a path relative to the *current working directory*.

These must be different for you.

Consider using [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths) with your relative path and [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname)